# MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS54005 in ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC web application that uses OAuth2 with Microsoft Identity services for authentication.

Specifically, I'm using the following code to configure the services:

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
 .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
 .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration);
```

On an intermittent, unpredictable frequency, when I start the web application in the debugger and attempt to get the login page, I get the following error:

> MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token.

What is causing this to occur? I think the application will acquire a new token each time I invoke the debugger; however, that does not appear to be the case. How can I force this to occur?

Answer (score 0):

When using Oauth2 code flow, after login to the "authorize" endpoint the application get a `code`. Then it will post this code to a "token" endpoint to get the `token`.
The `code` can be used only once to get the access `token`. If you reuse this code to get a token, you will get this error "OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#redeem-a-code-for-an-access-token
1.Get a code(vistit this URL in the browser and login to get the "code=" in the URL)
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7297/signin-oidc&scope=Files.Read`

2.use the code for 1st time
[image]

3.use the code for 2nd time
[image]

The problem is step 1. It doesn't give you a new code everytime you visit this endpoint. In my test, it gives me the same code if I visit in about less than 10 seconds(The browser has your login cookie so you don't have to login again). You could try login, close debug, then run debug again in a very short time. This error may occurred.